Pyinstaller exe file disappears when the project files (including the dist filder) is copied to a different directory
I made a simple chat app using python and c++. the python file is converted to .exe using pyinstaller. the cpp program takes help of that exe file generated from the python. After completing my work I made a zip of the whole project but when I unzip it on a different folder, one of the following happens:

the dist folder gets copied successfully but inside it a .tmp file gets generated automatically and then the exe and the tmp file gets deleted by itself
the dist folder doesn't fet copied, it asks for adminstrator permission but still fails to copy after giving the permission. (it happens from the second time and continues to happen when the exe file is being copied)

how do i fix it?
I tried using pyinstaller with and without --onefile. and I also tried deleting the exe and regenerating it but after deleting it the Permission error 13 something like that shows up in the command prompt which says copying the file failed. so I restarted my pc and it worked again...
